# Where can I find an already generated machine key on IIS?

Tags: iis, iis-7, machinekey

Not sure if it is possible, but I would like to know if I can retrieve a generated machine key from IIS 7 as I only see the option to generate a key (Generate Keys) on the "Machine Key" feature in IIS Manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, if you click the generated machine key and click apply, it will auto add it into the web.config file.

You could find it in your web application root path's web.config file as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <machineKey decryptionKey="3C32DFBDE785CEB8CDE5C29C4CC213A551218CA2C86644F4,IsolateApps" validationKey="C68F7949F9D89F727DF8A66AB1E907C60CA875A0C7AF383D1CB1798FCBE1A91C21A6A6672E0DC3E22284F071D9F830E95995640A32218A9B10C3BECFE4E753F5,IsolateApps" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```